# Not able to Spin a VM in Azure from image

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I have to Spin a new VM on Azure from the Image.I have to do this using powershell scripts and not from azure portal.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed#use-powershell) is the link I'm following to do it.

Now my question is , if I have a VM Image in say Resource Group : `ABC` and  I need to create a VM in Resource Group : `XYZ`, can it be done? And also I do not have access to Resource Group `ABC`.

And also where and how do I set my username and password. When we create a new VM from portal, it asks to set username and password. How to do that using powershell.

This is the command I'm trying to use.

```
New-AzureRmVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "XYZ" `
    -Name "TestVM" `
    -ImageName "Image1" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "VNET1" `
    -SubnetName "Subnet1"
```

When I run this command , it is giving the below error.

```
New-AzureRmVm : Can't find the image 'Image1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVm `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Is it because, `Image1` is in `ABC` resource group and not in `XYZ`. If yes, how do I specify it to map the image from`ABC` and create VM in `XYZ`.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to create a VM yourself if the image in another resource group and you do not have access to the resource group. 

If you really want to do that, you can ask the owner of the resource group copy the image to you or give you permission to copy. 

You can set the username and password when you create the VM using PowerShell command like this:

    $cred = Get-Credential
    New-AzureRmVm `
        -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupVM" `
        -Name "myVM" `
        -Location "EastUS" `
        -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
        -SubnetName "mySubnet" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to create a VM yourself if the image in another resource group and you do not have access to the resource group.

If you really want to do that, you can ask the owner of the resource group copy the image to you or give you permission to copy.

You can set the username and password when you create the VM using PowerShell command like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

The result will like this screenshot:
[image]

```
New-AzureRmVm `
        -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupVM" `
        -Name "myVM" `
        -Location "EastUS" `
        -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
        -SubnetName "mySubnet" `
        -SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup" `
        -PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress" `
        -Credential $cred
```

For more details, see [Create and Manage Windows VMs with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-vm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to powershell, So kindly bear with me. In the answer you have mentioned $cred = Get-Credential.  Where do I give the username and password exactly. I still didn't get it. Say suppose I want to set username as : 'adminuser' and password as 'adminpassword' for the new VM, where do i mention these?

Comment: @CrazyCoder When you execute the PowerShell command, it will come out a window which you can input your username and password. See my update.

Comment: okay and In the answer you have missed Image name in the parameters. So in the same cmdlet, can I include ImageName as well?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, you can set the image in the command [`New-AzureRmVm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/new-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.7.0) with parameter `-Image`.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you cannot spin up new VM from image which is present in another resource group.

**Note: *The image needs to be in the same resource group where you want to create the VM.***

Try to create spin up VM in the same resource group where the image is available.

```
New-AzureRmVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "ABC" `
    -Name "TestVM" `
    -ImageName "Image1" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "VNET1" `
    -SubnetName "Subnet1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can store your image in a blob storage and then on creating the VM pass the url of this .VHD file.

To set your own password on create your VM just need this:

```
$UserName = "example"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "example" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
```

and then take a look on the following command to specify the config of System Machine *[Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmoperatingsystem?view=azurermps-6.7.0)*, there's a parameter to pass the credential object like:

```
Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Credential $psCred -VM $configMachine -Windows -ComputerName $nameMachine -EnableAutoUpdate:$false
```